# How to find SQL server database name and the table names that an app uses from Access?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have an MS Access app that uses data from different tables. I need to find the database and the tables being used by this app.

I am using SQL Server 2005.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: does the app connect using its own login?

Comment: @SEarle1986 I don't see any login window pop up but yes it connects and works.

Comment: I mean what database login / account does it connect to the database with? Is it a unique SQL login, or is using windows authentication?

Comment: @SEarle1986 It could be via an ODBC DSN.

Comment: @SEarle1986 It uses windows authentication

Comment: @Dai  I am looking at "External Data' tab and I don't see "ODBC Database" here.

Answer (score 1):

Hum, there are quite a few moving parts here.

but, first up, it may well depend on what kind of Access applcation you are using. (there are several types).

So, you want to first check/see what the file extension is here. In most cases, the extension will be accDB (2007 onwards).

However, you might be using a ADP (file extension .adp). So, this is the FIRST thing you need to check.

I mean, assuming this is accDB, then of course when you open access, you should see a list of tables in the left nav pane, say like this:

[image]

And if you "hover" your cursor over a table - as I did above then you can see that the tool tip shows the database server in question.

And of course, note that you see "different" icons for different types of tables.

so, tables without a -> (arrow) are LOCAL tables not linked.

but, if a table has the "arrow", then the table is a external (linked table).

[image]

And if you look, you can also see some Orange colored linked tables. Those are SharePoint tables (and once again, you can hover over those to see the location (I did not hover over those, since they actually are SharePoint tables on a site).

So, the above is the most simple approach to quick see the tables.

As noted, the other way is to fire up the linked table manger.

[image]

And that will and should show the current table links, like this:

[image]

Note that the above does not show the server name, but only the table + database name.

Last but not least, you can hit ctrl-g (debug window), and say type in this

```
? currentdb.TableDefs("tblAnimals2").Connect
```

(in above, replace tblAnimals2 with a valid linked table name from the nav pane).

Output: (on one line, broken up for ease of reading here).

```
ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=ALBERTKALLAL-PC\SQLEXPRESS;
Trusted_Connection=Yes;APP=Microsoft Office 2010;
DATABASE=Test4;Network=DBMSLPCN
```

However, if this is a ADP applcation, then linked tables don't show nor exist in the traditional sense, and you have to go file->info, and you see a "server" setting, like this:

[image]

So, first issue here, is what kind of Access applcation? It is either a adp, or accDB (or maybe really old, and a mdb). If you using a ADP, then linked tables work VERY differnt, and you not see a linked table manager. You have to use the "server" connection.  In a "adp", then your tables will NOT be linked, but they are still residing on sql server.

But, adp's can't be used after Access 2010, so in most cases, what version of Access you are using don't matter, but in the case of a adp, then it is a big deal.

and of course, you want to know if you have a accDE (or mde), as that is a compiled applcation, and design changes, and all source (Visual Basic) code will have been stripped out during the compile process. So, as noted, what version of access, and even more important is the file extension type you have.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the detailed answer. Unfortunately, the extension type is `.mde`. I think I did find the tables in Files->Info->View And Edit Database Properties but I still find the database. I am using Office 365 For Enterprise. Access version 2202 Build 14931.20132

Comment: ok, then we NOT use adp (that is a big detail to take off this issue). So, mde, that is compiled - means you can't see code, can't change forms. I would attempt to find the "source code" used to build that mde. However, all of the other (first) screen caps and methods should show, should work, and allow you to work here. I would consider holding down the shift key during startup - if you lucky, that's not been disabled, and you will get/see the whole access UI.

Comment: So, the navigation pane on the left side should show the files (change it to all objects) - as noted, try holding down shift key during the startup of the application, and as noted if shift key by-pass to startup not been disabled, then you should get + see the whole access UI - including the nav pane on the left side like my first screen caps.